# Search string on li element then hide the class of lionly if not found

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to search for a specified string in an li element, and only remove the class if the li element does not contain that string.

```
<input type="text" name="search"/>
<div class="myClass">
  <ul>
    <li>computer</li>
    <li>mobile</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  <ul>
    <li>car</li>
    <li>jeep</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

When I type 'car' in the searchfield then I want to hide/remove all classes except those class containing searched string.

Comment: Have you tried to write JS code for that? Ex. bind keyXXX event on textbox, search for text in the `.myClass` and then hide if text not found.

Comment: Don't worry about your ability to write English. People are able to read a lot if you take care of putting interpunction in your text. Start your sentences with a capital, and end it with a full stop (.). This makes **anything** a lot more readable.

Comment: That said, I don't understand what you mean with removing/hiding classes on `li` elements, while your `li` elements do not have any classes associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

**1:** if you want to hide all `li`s from the page and show only `li` which has any letter that match input value then try this code

```
$('.input').on('keyup', function () {
  $('li').hide();
  $('li[class*="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvfuk1q0/1/

**2:** If you want to show all `li`s and hide only who doesn't match input value letters ( on `keyup` event) then you can use this one

```
$('.input').on('keyup', function () {
  $('li').hide();
  $('li[class*="' + $(this).val() + '"]').show();

  if($(this).val().length == 0) {
    $('li').show();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Lvfuk1q0/2/

### NOTE:

If you want to show `li`s which only **starts** with input value then change `class*` to `class^`.

Comment: It doesn't work. It work when you type class name complately.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly, you want to hide any `li` element that does not contain the searched term.

You can use `indexOf()` method on `input` event like this:

```js
$(document).on('input', '#searchInp', function() {

  var li = $('.myClass').find('ul > li');
  var val = $(this).val();

  //Remove all .hidden classes
  li.removeClass('hidden')

  if (val && val.length > 0) {

    li.each(function() {
      var that = $(this);
      var txt = that.text();

      //If searched term is not found into li's text
      if (txt.indexOf(val) == -1) {
        //Add .hidden class to the specific element
        that.addClass('hidden');
      }

    });
  }
});
```

```css
.hidden { display:none }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="searchInp" type="text" name="search"/>
<div class="myClass">
  <ul>
    <li>computer</li>
    <li>mobile</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="myClass">
  <ul>
    <li>car</li>
    <li>jeep</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```